# SMTP: Change Message-ID domain in sending emails from Laravel 5.7 (Swift Mailer)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, smtp, swiftmailer, email-headers

Laravel 5.7 sends emails using Swift Mailer.

By default, all sent emails will have the `Message-ID` header with the domain `swift.generated` (eg. `Message-ID: <90b9835f38bb441bea134d3ac815dd6f@swift.generated>`).

I would like to change the domain `swift.generated` to for example `my-domain.com`.

How can I change this for all emails?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Edit the file config/mail.php and define your domain near the end:

```
    'domain' => 'yourdomain.com',
```

2. In the command line, create a new listener:

```
    php artisan make:listener -e 'Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending' MessageSendingListener
```

3. Edit the newly created listener and make it look as follows (do NOT implement ShouldQueue):

```
    <?php
    /**
     * Set the domain part in the message-id generated by Swift Mailer
     */

    namespace App\Listeners;

    use Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending;
    use Swift_Mime_IdGenerator;

    class MessageSendingListener
    {
        /**
         * Create the event listener.
         *
         * @return void
         */
        public function __construct()
        {
            //
        }

        /**
         * Handle the event.
         *
         * @param  MessageSending  $event
         * @return void
         */
        public function handle(MessageSending $event)
        {
            $event->message->setId((new Swift_Mime_IdGenerator(config('mail.domain')))->generateId());
        }
    }
```

4. Register the listener in app/Providers/EventServiceProvider:

```
        protected $listen = [

           // [...]

            \Illuminate\Mail\Events\MessageSending::class => [
                 \App\Listeners\MessageSendingListener::class,
            ],
         ];
```

That's it, enjoy! :)

Comment: Awesome! Works perfect, thank you! This should be already included in Laravel like this. Maybe in Laravel 6.0. :)

Comment: It is included in laravel 7.0 for sure, just need to do the first step, the rest is already done

Answer (score 2):

Just found a correct way to change `@swift.generated` in message ID.

Add this code to your `AppServiceProvider->boot()` method:

```
\Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance()
        ->register('mime.idgenerator.idright')
        ->asValue(config('mail.domain'));
```

`config('mail.domain')` is a custom config entry so you can change it to whatever you want.

Tested in Laravel 6, maybe will work with 5.* versions too.

Also you can find many interesting configs in this file:
`vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/dependency_maps/mime_deps.php`